# How do I assign to a variable in a for loop in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, variable-assignment

Noob, working on an encryption problem, and I want to iterate through combinations in an array in C, i.e. aaa, aab, aac, aba, etc. and then pass each combination to a function (to check whether that combination is the correct code).

I can print what I want to console no problem, i.e. aa, ab, ba, bb, but can't get those values into my temp variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *word = "ab";

    char * temp[3];
    //temp[2] = '\0'; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            temp[0] = &word[i];
            temp[1] = &word[j];
            printf("%s\n", *temp);
            // printf("%c", word[i]);
            // printf("%c\n", word[j]);
            // pass_temp_to_function(temp);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting ab, ab, b, b, when I should be getting aa, ab, ba, bb (with my above code), and don't know why or how to correct it or otherwise find the answer, hence my Noobish question.

Comment: I think you want a `char temp[3];` instead.

Comment: And don't forget to initialize `temp`, as strings in C need to be null-terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you've carefully coded it to create zero warnings even though it is very wrong, with all sorts of array of strings, and pointers to characters being flown around.

You want to have a *single string* of 2 characters, for that an array of 3 characters is sufficient:

```
char temp[3];
temp[2] = '\0'; 

...
    temp[0] = word[i];
    temp[1] = word[j];

    puts(temp); // less typing but essentially the same as printf("%s\n", temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that the original poster review chapter 5 of [Kernighan and Ritchie](https://www.linuxprogramming.ca/download/kernighan_ritchie.pdf).

```
/* main.c - This is a novice program. */
/* Copyright (C) 2019 Robin Miyagi https://www.linuxprogramming.ca/
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as
 * published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the
 * License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
 * WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 675 Mass Ave, Cambridge, MA 02139, USA.
 */

#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
# define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <error.h>

/*
 * Declared global so that the linker can find it.....................
 */
int main (void);

/*
 * Implementation.....................................................
 */
int
main
(void)
{
  char temp[3];
  int i;
  int j;

  temp[2] = '\0';
  for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
      {
        temp[0] = 'a' + i;
        temp[1] = 'a' + j;
        printf ("%s\n", temp);  /* temp ---> beginning of array of char. */
      }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`temp` is a pointer to pointer to `char`. I don't know why your code is constructed the way it is, so I'm just going to assume there is a reason.

```
            // printf("%c", word[i]);
            // printf("%c\n", word[j]);
```

Yup these lines didn't work. A slight mistake. Easy fix:

```
            printf("%c", temp[i][0]);
            printf("%c\n", temp[j][0]);
```

We have to dereference the `char*` again to get back to the `char`. I could have written `*(temp[i])` but `temp[i][0]` is easier to read.

Comment: Your 'fix' doesn't make sense.  `word` is of type `char *`, so `word[i]` is already a `char` and you can't dereference it.  Did you mean to have `temp` there?

Comment: @NateEldredge fixed

Answer (score 0):

With the above help, I was able to get my code working as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char * word = "abc";

    char temp[3];
    temp[2] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(word); j++){
            temp[0] = word[i];
            temp[1] = word[j];
            puts(temp);
        }
    }
    printf("%s", temp);

    return 0;
}
```

// displays aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc, cc (duplicate)